# C# convert bytes of serialized object to string

Tags: c#, regex, serialization, tcp, deserialization

I have a problem at the moment that I don't know how to solve.

The technical progress is sending bytes from a TCPClient to a TCPServer.
The sent message is as example: 1-[BYTES-OF-SERIALIZED-OBJECT]
Now I have to convert these bytes (from a byte array) to a string to work with regex.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this? Because when I convert the byte array to a string no encoding works to decode.
Maybe I have to convert the serialized bytes in the square brackets to something different and then convert it back? Any idea?

Comment: You might look for: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`

Comment: As i wrote, no encoding worked. When i try it and show the full message in a MessageBox i only get "1-[" and the bytes are missing.

Comment: So, you're trying to regex non-asc-ii data. I googled it, first suggestion: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df18cca9-5e54-410e-a5c5-74efc7b52e29/does-c-supoort-binary-regular-expression?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem. I have no problem with regex

Comment: I think you have to remove '1-[' and the closing square bracket. But you gave us no clue what kind of data the bytes are. Do you have a sample message ?

Comment: The data are bytes of a serialized object ...

Comment: Why convert to string at all? Some regular expression systems allow `\xHH` or `\uHHHH` where each `H` is a hexadecimal digit. Both are allowed in .NET, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#character_escapes

Comment: I forgot to say that it's possible that the sent message is as example: 1-[BYTES-OF-SERIALIZED-OBJECT]2-[BYTES-OF-SERIALIZED-OBJECT2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to serialize the objects to a base64 encode string. The sent message is now as example: (1)[BASE64STRING-OF-SERIALIZED-OBJECT].
Now I can work with regex and don't have to format the base64 string again.

Comment: This most likely happened because the data contained a null char (a byte with value 0). The null char usually indicates end-of-string, which causes most controls to stop render text after that point. Base64 should always be used when sending strings that are not always text.